# send PHP variable to javascript function via HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to send a PHP variable to a Javascript funtion using HTML. I dont know if it is possible or not. I am a newbie.

This is all the code in both the files, index.php and abc.php
P.S. I have changed the file name from index.html to index.php

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-transitional.dtd">
<?php
require("../php/abc.php");
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Some Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="file.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="here.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
<noscript>
Your browser does not support Javascript!!
</noscript>
<table id="content">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="scroll"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="colorpicker" valign="top">
            <img src="palette.png" id="palette" alt="Color Palette" border="1" onclick="getColor(event);" />
            <br />
            <input id="color" type="hidden" readonly="true" value="#000000" />
            <span id="sampleText">
            (text will look like this)
            </span>
        </td> 
    </tr>
</table>

<div>
    <input type="text" id="userName" maxlength="50" size="10" onblur="javascript: check('<?php echo $phpVariable; ?>');" />
    <input type="text" id="messageBox" maxlength="2000" size="50" onkeydown="handleKey(event);" />
    <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="sendMessage();"  />
    <input type="button" value="Delete All" onclick="deleteMessages();"  />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javscript function

```
function check(param_name)
{ 
 var oUser=document.getElementById("userName"); 
 oUser.value = param_name;
}
```

abc.php

```
if(isset($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['action'])) {
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$action = $_POST['action'];

if($action == 'joined') {
    $phpVariable = user_joined($user_name);
}

function user_joined($user_name) {
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

//Create connection

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$user_name  = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($user_name));

$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES ('$user_name')";
$query = "INSERT INTO table_name2 (column_name) VALUES ('$user_name')";

$result = $conn->query($query);

if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error in inserting: " . $sql. "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

return $user_name;

$conn->close();

}
```

Comment: This is a correct syntax!

Comment: Using a pseudo-protocol, the javascript:, is not really a good habit to get into.

Comment: This should work. Whats wrong with it? Are you getting errors? what is the value of `$phpVariable` ?

Comment: @joyBlanks, instead of getting a value in the phpVariable, all I get is "<?php echo $phpVariable; ?>" in the userName value. Dont know where I am going wrong.

Comment: @CodeGodie, irrespective of the value of phpVariable, it shows me undefined first, if I try to change that, it shows me '<?php echo $phpVariable; ?>'

Comment: then you dont have PHP running on your server. the file should be named with `.php` in the end, like `index.php` is that how you have it?

Comment: Where are you setting the value for $phpVariable?

Comment: I am setting value of $phpVariable in abc.php. Included that at the start of index.html

Comment: Rename index.html to index.php

Comment: if you are using <php tags you cant do in a html, it will be treated as text rather rename the file to index.php

Comment: @Kashish show all the code for `index.php` and `abc.php` so we can further inspect

Comment: The way to go as mentioned before is to rename index.html to index.php since PHP is not parsed on .html files

Comment: @CodeGodie I have put full code for index.php and abc.php..Please see if this helps you.

Comment: @Devian I have already changed index,html to index.php. Now, it gives me error saying undefined variable $phpVariable.

Comment: In your index.php it needs an action property to be posted in order to be able to see the phpVariable...

Comment: @Devian I have taken care of action property in another php file. I am sure this is not the issue, since it is entering the function user_joined and my sql queries works fine.

Comment: So you can start Debugging, Set something random on top of your abc.php to the $phpVariable and check if works

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="nametxt" />
<button id="btn-check"></button>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function (){

   $("#btn-check").click(function(){

       var name = $('#nametxt').val();

       var login = {
           parameter: name
       };

        $.ajax({

              type: 'POST',
              url:  'file.php',
              data: login,
              datatype: 'json'

        }).done(function(data) {

      console.log(data);
     }); 

   });

});
```

PHP

```
<?php

//do some

echo information; -- this way return parameters

?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do I have to exactly do with the PHP file

Comment: ajax is not necessary here

Comment: for example

  `$iden = $_POST['parameter'];`
 
this way capture the parameter and so use echo for return you need, i have an example, wait give you for pastebin

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Can you please provide the pastebin?

Comment: can you exactly what it you want for help you, what you want to do with php, send parameter, check if parameter is posible, if exist or what

Answer (score 0):

As you have written, the way to output the value of a PHP variable to an HTML page is by doing `<?php echo $phpVariable ?>`. In newer versions of PHP (and in older ones where the setting was turned on), you can shorten this to `<?= $phpVariable ?>`.

You are getting an 'undefined variable' warning probably because the `$phpVariable` is not getting set. In your code, this variable is only initialized if `$action == 'joined'`. If you want it to have a default value, give it one first:

```
$phpVariable = null;
// note that three equals signs are not necessary here
// but a good habit for cases where it matters
if ($action === 'joined') { ... }
```

When you output the PHP variable into a JavaScript string, you should escape the output so that you don't leave your visitors vulnerable to XSS (cross-site scripting) attacks. In this case, `json_encode` should be sufficient. However, since your JavaScript is not within a `<script>` tag, but rather within an `onblur` attribute, you have to escape any characters which are special in HTML. Since you're using double quotes around the attribute value, `htmlspecialchars` is sufficient for that. So in all, you will output `htmlspecialchars(json_encode($phpVariable))`. The reason for all this is that you don't want to rely on your input being clean -- mistakes will be made and when they do, you don't want to let someone attack your users.

```
<input type="text" id="userName" maxlength="50" size="10" 
    onblur="javascript: check('<?= htmlspecialchars(json_encode($phpVariable)) ?>');" />
```

Since we've given a default value (`null`) for `$phpVariable` and we are calling the `check` function with it, we should add a "check" to the `check` function to ensure that we got a real value, like this:

```
// you should use camelCase or under_scores, but not both, for consistency
function check(paramName) { 
    // loose equals to match null or undefined
    if (paramName == null) { 
        return;
    }
    var oUser = document.getElementById("userName"); 
    oUser.value = paramName;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to be really careful about your function inputs, you could verify that `paramName` is a string and that it has a nonzero length, but in a dynamically typed language like JavaScript, doing all these checks manually sometimes becomes a losing battle.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But it is still not working.. I am still getting the "undefined variable: $phpVaribale" error.

Answer (score -3):

This is not going to work as-is because PHP is executed server-side and JavaScript is executed client-side.

In order to do this, you're going to have to make an AJAX call to a PHP file and then use JavaScript on the results.

Comment: youre right that ajax is an option but it is not necessary. PHP should be able to send that string to his JS script

Comment: I set up a test page and all I get were echos of the literal code. Not the results.

Comment: You are wrong. You can print a variable wherever you want in an html code by adding <?php echo "smth"; ?>.
Whatsover you can also do this with Ajax but it is not Required.

Comment: When I created my test file I had two lines: <?php $myVar = "testString"; ?> and then my JavaScript which was, in <script> tags, alert('<?php echo $myVar; ?>'); but the alert was the literal string of: <?php echo $myVar; ?> instead of "testString". Changed the '' to "" and same result.